# How to reverse modulo of this steps?

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic

I am a programmer and I found this challenge to find the original number of this operation starting from the fact that I only have this data:
We have n = 8;

```
    n = 8 (it's a variable)
    Step 1 -> n + 7     = 15
    Step 2 -> 15 * 10   = 150
    Step 3 -> 150 % n   = 6
```

The costants in this algorithm are: 7 and 10.
n is alwaise added to 7 and the result it is multiplied by 10 after that we do the modulo operation of 150 to n.

How can i reverse this algorithm to find from 6 the original value that was 8, knowing only this data?. I didn't mention that sorry, n can't be grater than 9.

I'm banging my head, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What does `150 % n = 6` mean?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos $150 \equiv 6 \mod n$. It's the notation for C++, at least. More specifically, 6 is the least non-negative representative of $150 \mod n$.

Comment: If $n$ can't be greater than 9, why don't you just compute all the possible values and use a lookup table? Since $n$ can't be greater than $9$, $70\mod{n}$ can't be greater than $8$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to compute $10(n+7) = 10n+70\mod{n}$. Since $10n\equiv 0\mod{n}$, the result is always simply $70\mod{n}$, or the remainder on dividing $70$ by $n$.

Thus you are trying to solve $70\equiv k\mod{n}$, or $70-k\equiv 0\mod{n}$, for $n$. This means that $70-k$ is a multiple of $n$, so $n$ can be any factor of $70-k$. In your example, $k=6$, so you look for factors of $70-6=64$. Possible answers are $1$, $2$, $4$, $8$, $16$, $32$, $64$. If you have more information about $n$, you might be able to choose the desired answer algorithmically from among these.

Comment: OK i think i'm understanding

Comment: Anything else I can clear up?

Answer (score 2):

Because this is modular arithmetic you will get many answers...but, if you know more information you can narrow it down. It is straight forward to find the only choices of $n$ that your answer can be....in this case $C \equiv (n+7)10 \mod n \equiv 70 \mod n \implies C \equiv 70 \mod n $ every time. Just find all the n for which this is true, there is only finitely many, and use other info to restrict further.

For your example, $C=6$, so $6 \equiv 70 \mod n \implies 0 \equiv 64 \mod n$ so the solution for n could be $\{8,16,32,64\}$.

**Edit**: so that means, your answer divides 64 but is greater than 6. So, that list are all the possibilities.

Comment: Why does it have to be greater than $6$?

Comment: Because if you have $x \mod n$, where $x$ has been reduced modulo $n$ the answer is always $x<n$, so if $n=4$ for example after reducing by 4 you will never get 6. And the result of your original algorithm got 6 after reduction, so that means $n$ can't be 4 or 2. It has to be at least 8.

Comment: Ah, but for example $70\equiv 6\mod{2}$ since they are both $0\mod{2}$.

Comment: @rogerl: I do not see your point.If $n=2$ his algorithm would return $0$ not $6$.

Answer (score 0):

If I am right, this is your mapping:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline n & result \\
\hline 1 & 0\\
\hline 2 & 0\\
\hline 3 & 1\\
\hline 4 & 2\\
\hline 5 & 0\\
\hline 6 & 4\\
\hline 7 & 0\\
\hline 8 & 6\\
\hline 9 & 7\\
\hline\end{array}$$

Reverse it and this is what you get:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline result & n \\
\hline 0 & 1,2,5\;\text{or}\;7 \\
\hline 1 & 3\\
\hline 2 & 4\\
\hline 4 & 6\\
\hline 6 & 8\\
\hline 7 & 9\\
\hline\end{array}$$

Comment: i updated now the answer, n can't be greater than 9

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly... If the problem is finite, as it seems it is, then why not just draw a table???